# How to set the visual and collision at ones using sdf to use the same geometry and pose

Tags: gazebo-model, collision, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I like to define the visual and collision apparans of a link at ones. 
Is there a way to define variables? 
Or is there a way to say visual == collision? 
The example shows a link which has the same collision and visual dimensions is it possible to write that shorter:

```
<link name='Wall_01'>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <collision name='collision_01'>
    <pose>0 0.05 1 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <box>
        <size>5 0.1 2</size>
      </box>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
  <visual name='visual_01'>
    <pose>0 0.05 1 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <box>
        <size>5 0.1 2</size>
      </box>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
      </script>
    </material>
  </visual>
</link>
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4606/how-to-set-the-visual-and-collision-at-ones-using-sdf-to-use-the-same-geometry-and-pose/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/491/markus-bader/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There have been discussions about this, but no pull requests.

One proposal is to use xacro ([gazebo issue #210](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/210/incorporate-xacro-into-sdf)), which could be used to insert blocks of repeated sdf elements. This would require xacro to be packaged independently from ROS to avoid a gazebo dependency on ROS.

There were some alternative syntax proposals in [gazebo issue #427](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/427/sdf-geometry-enhancements). One of the concerns with expanding the syntax is overwhelming complexity.

Feel free to chime in with either or both of these feature requests.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/491/markus-bader/) on 2013-11-04**:
Using xacro was my final solution